# Dotnet In-Memory DataStore/Datasource for Production

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a solution to store data in memory while beeing able to query this.
As far as I understand EF Core inmemory database should not be used in production since it is only made for testing purposes.

The data is generated at startup from the application itself and should be accessible really fast during runtime of the application ( a lot of lookups ).

The reason not to use a Dict is that there are a lot of search parameters inbetween those informations that are generated at startup. And a list with LINQ is not due to performance concerns.

Redis is not used due to the overhead with the whole connection stuff.
Even if I don't care regarding the recommendation not to use EF Core inmemory db, isn't the overhead there to convert all of the querys to SQL and then "request" it ?

Any advice or alternative is appreciated.
Regards!

Comment: You can use it in production if you want to, but it won't work in a web farm scenario because there's no way for different instances to share the data, and if the server restarts you'll lose all the data permanently. Those reasons are probably why you shouldn't use it, but it depends on your use cases. However, EntityFramework isn't going to be faster than just using a dictionary, it will be the opposite as it's effectively a wrapper around some in-memory lists/arrays etc, and will use LINQ.

Comment: [SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) might be your next best friend ;)

Comment: @PeterCsala currently only the Microsoft SQLite provider supports true in-memory operations. The provider implemented by the SQLite team uses a temp cache file.

Comment: You can have a look at NMemory.

Comment: Are there no real alternatives to Datatables ? 

With a Database even in memory there are a lot of layers that just add overhead. With EF Core even more.